# Laravel Database Insert Data

Tags: database, laravel

I have a question about using create method and model for inserting data into database. After I've tried it, I came to a conclusion that the name of the fields in database, the name of the input in forms, and the name of the fields in $fillables, all three of them have to be the same, is this true? Or is there better way to do this?

Comment: It doesn't have to be this way but it's certainly a lot easier if you do it this way. If they have different names you will have to do some manual renaming of the keys of your array

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is true, but this doesn't mean that this is the only way. this is the best practice you can say because we easily remember it while working on controller and view. we don't need to remember the name that we have given in view.

but you can use different names too for view and controller separately.

Comment: but, if i use different names then what should I do to make it work?